# show servlet result in textfields using jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

**JSP**

```
<div id="feedback" class="statusbar"></div>
```

**In jQuery**

```
$("#categorySave").click(function(){        
$getCode = document.getElementById("catCode").value;
$getName = document.getElementById("catName").value;
$getDesc = document.getElementById("catDesc").value;
$getDepID = $("select option:selected").val();

$(':text').val('');

$('#feedback').html('<img src="images/loading.gif"/>Processing....');

$.post("CategoryOperation", {
    catCode:$getCode,
    catName:$getName,
    catDesc:$getDesc,
    catID:$getDepID
}, function(html) {
    $("#feedback").html(html);         
});
});
```

**In Servlet (CategoryOperation)**

```
out.println("<div>Record Inserted!</div>");
```

When I press the save button (id=categorySave), it shows the message in div (id=feedback) as record inserted. The above code it working fine. But I want a little change now, that 
When record is inserted successfully, it shows result on text fields rather than on div (id=feedback).

Suppose,CategoryOperation (Servlet) print the followings two after process,

```
out.println("Record Inserted!");
out.println("1");
```

Now I want to show the above two output in the **text fields** respectively, and they have the 
following ID

```
id="Result"
id="Key"
```

How can I do this, in above jquery code snippet , by writing the following code or any other easy way

```
$('#Result').val();
$('#Key').val();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let the servlet return a parseable object format instead of plain text, such as JSON or XML. jQuery has builtin support for both.

Here's a JSON example:

```
String json = String.format("{\"result\": \"%s\", \"key\": \"%s\"}", "Record Inserted!", "1");
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

*([Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) may make JSON formatting much easier)*

which needs to be processed as follows:

```
function(data) {
    $("#Result").val(data.result);
    $("#Key").val(data.key);
}
```

#### See also:

- [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)